# grid view display image

Tags: c#, image, gridview

i have a ActivityType field in my db. the values are [1,2,3].
each number represent type of activity.
i want to present the type in gridview as image.

i have 3 images

- activity type 1 = avtivity_choise.jpg
- activity type 2 = activity_text.jpg
- activity type 3 = activity_count.jpg

i have tried to do so with template field but i need switch case statement to transfer the number to image url...

Comment: What type of GridView are you referring to? There are GridView for WPF (`System.Windows.Controls`), Windows Forms (`System.Windows.Forms`), and ASP.NET (`System.Web.UI.WebControls`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event. Use something like the following:

```
void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       int type = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[typeCellIndex].Text);
       Image img = (Image) e.Row.Cells[imageCellIndex].FindControl(imageID);
       switch type
       {
          case 1:
          {
             img.ImageUrl = "avtivity_choise.jpg";
          }
          ......
       }

   }

 }
```

You can also bind your image field to a database field. Refer to the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/imagegalleryingridview.aspx

Comment: Trying to get an answer to my issue here. I have two images which I want to display in a grid which lists students. One of the image will be displayed depending on whether a student is enrolled or not, This view I have is strongly typed, how can I get this to work?